# Exploding column in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, explode

I have a shp with a column `NOM_CONCAT` and I can not explode it to have a unique information,
Each time, I have the same error message and I can't find solutions.

```
#TypeError: explode() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

[SHAPEFILE](https://we.tl/t-RrOE1AGsYU)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime
import sys
import geopandas as gpd


gdf = gpd.read_file('RSF_Fiche_Canalisation-power_shp_ME_Position-04012021.shp')
gdf['NOM_CONCAT'] = gdf['NOM_CONCAT'].str.split(',  ')
gdf.NOM_CONCAT = gdf.NOM_CONCAT.fillna({i: [] for i in gdf.index})
gdf = gdf.explode('NOM_CONCAT')
print ("temp_complet_explode",gdf)
```

Current situation:

[image: current situation]

Situation I hope:

[image: situation hope]

Comment: `geopandas.explode` explodes multipart geometry, not a column, string or list.

Comment: This can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954668/how-to-convert-column-with-list-of-values-into-rows-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the doc:

[image: geodataframe explode doc]
Source: https://geopandas.org/reference.html

It's a method which applies directly on your `GeoDataFrame` object, therefore any extra argument you pass will be counted as a 2nd argument, hence the error you face. Please notice that `GeoDataFrame.explode()` is intended to:

> Explode muti-part geometries into multiple single geometries.

Therefore, the following is working because all geometries are multilines, so it splits them into new rows, each hosting one of the part from the original geometry:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'identifiant': [11,12,13,14,15],
    'nom_concat': ['123abc',['123def','123ghj'],['123klm','123nop'],'123qrs','123tuv'],
    'geometry': [wkt.loads(mlt) for mlt in 5*'MULTILINESTRING((3 4,10 50,20 25),(-5 -8,-10 -8,-15 -4))+'[:-1].split('+')]
})
```

which results in:
[image: results]

And calling `.explode()` will actually explode your geometries:
[image: result after explode]

But if you do not have multiple geometries:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'identifiant': [11,12,13,14,15],
    'nom_concat': ['123abc',['123def','123ghj'],['123klm','123nop'],'123qrs','123tuv'],
    'geometry': [wkt.loads(mlt) for pkt in 5*'MULTILINESTRING((3 4,10 50,20 25),(-5 -8,-10 -8,-15 -4))+'[:-1].split('+')]
})
```

calling `.explode()` will return your original dataframe:

[image: result of explode on simple geometries]

What you want is probably to use [pandas explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method instead, which is waiting for a **column** parameter:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
import pandas as pd

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'identifiant': [11,12,13,14,15],
    'nom_concat': ['123abc',['123def','123ghj'],['123klm','123nop'],'123qrs','123tuv'],
    'geometry': [wkt.loads(mlt) for pkt in 5*'MULTILINESTRING((3 4,10 50,20 25),(-5 -8,-10 -8,-15 -4))+'[:-1].split('+')]
})

df = pd.DataFrame(gdf2) # convert to a panda DataFrame instance
type(df)

df.explode('nom_concat') # call pandas explode method on a column
```

[image: pandas explode method applied]

You can finally convert it back to a GeoDataFrame:

```
exploded_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.explode('nom_concat'))
```

Beware of the index changes after the explosion. You can obviously change it depending on your needs, e.g. with [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).